# Mapping rules from UML to column oriented NoSQL databases

Tags: cassandra, uml, class-diagram, column-oriented, nosql

As i'm working in a new project of translation of UML class diagram to a NoSQL cassandra database. I'm struggling to find basic translation rules analogic to relational model. As i read in the [cassandra documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/ddl/dataModelingApproach.html), it is queries oriented modeling. But is there any generic rules concepts before implement it. Please help

Comment: The documentation you reference gives a nice example on how to do that. What exactly is it that you do not understand there?

Comment: What i need is a practical approach to go from a UML class diagram to a cassandra database schema. This is for impementing after an automated app which takes an UML class diagram as an input and gives you a CQL database schema script. I need to learn the mapping rules between class diagram and oriented column nosql database

Comment: You should go with the answer of @doanduyhai. The schema in this paper can also be represented using UML. Else your question would be too broad to give an answer here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a written research paper that proposes a new concept: the **Chebotko** diagram, named after its author, to model data and tables in **Cassandra**

The research paper is here: http://www.cs.wayne.edu/andrey/papers/TR-BIGDATA-05-2015-CKL.pdf

There is also a tool called **KDM** to help you model data in **Cassandra**.

- blog post [part1](http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/kdm-an-automated-data-modeling-tool-for-apache-cassandra-pt-1/)
- blog post [part2](http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/kdm-an-automated-data-modeling-tool-for-apache-cassandra-pt-2/)

Comment: Actually the problem is i'm constrainted to use a translation from an UML class diagram to a cassandra database schema. I'm trying to make up a tab with two columns where for every component of UML class diagram such as a class or attribute i put the correspondance such as a table or column in cassandra. Do you think is the right approach to the problem ?

Comment: You'll have a simple relationship between UML entity and Cassandra table as well as entity attribute and Cassandra columns. For the 1-N, N-N relationship, you'll need to work out with Cassandra PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: You need to design the data model and especially the primary key for N-N relationship

Comment: Great thanks for you helps. I was able to make it with the mapping rules. For the automation of the transformation Class Diagram-CQL the authors specify that we need to implement mapping patterns. In this document, only one pattern is explain and the reference of the link no longer exists have you any resources to help me with ?

Comment: Sorry I don't have any other resources than the one posted above. Usually I design the data model myself, I don't use any tool